# Parámetro axis en numpy.all()

Tags: python, numpy

La duda es bastante clara y directa. No termino de entender el parámetro `axis` de la función de numpy, `numpy.all()` y me gustaría ver si alguien me puede ayudar a entenderlo.

Por ejemplo, yo para saber si un color concreto aparece en una imagen hago:

```
matches = np.all(img == (0,255,0), axis=2)
if matches.any() == True:
    print('Hay verde en la imagen')
```

Pero, ¿que significa ese `axis=2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como norma general este argumento en NumPy, como su nombre indica, es el eje del array sobre el que se realiza la operación.

Si tenemos un array de tres dimensiones, `axis=0` se refiere al eje <kbd>X</kbd> (filas), `axis=1` al eje <kbd>Y</kbd> (columnas) y `axis=2` al eje <kbd>z</kbd>. En realidad el concepto es más simple (en un array de más de tres dimensiones se complica la explicación anterior), el eje indica el orden del índice para indizar sobre un elemento en el array.

En tu caso, tienes una matriz tridimensional precisamente, de la forma:

> ```
> img  = np.array([[[2, 5, 4], [4, 6, 7], [8, 1, 6]],
>                  [[7, 5, 6], [6, 9, 1], [7, 5, 6]],
>                  [[2, 8, 5], [2, 5, 4], [5, 2, 9]], 
>                  [[3, 4, 2], [8, 3, 4], [3, 2, 8]]])
> ```

en este caso sería una imagen de 3 pixeles de ancho por 4 pixeles de alto, en la que cada pixel (color) se representa como un array de tres valores (RGB). El eje 0 representa las coordenadas <kbd>X</kbd> de cada pixel, el eje 1 las coordenadas  <kbd>Y</kbd> y el eje 2 el color (en forma de valores RGB, RGBA, BGR, etc). Suponiendo que trabajamos con RGB, si queremos acceder al valor `R` del tercer pixel de la cuarta fila (`R, G, B = [3, 2, 8]`) necesitamos usar tres índices:

```
# Eje   0  1  2
>>> img[3, 2, 0]
3
```

- El índice 3 se corresponde con el eje 0, que permite indizar sobre la fila (coordenada <kbd>X</kbd>):

  ```
  >>> img[3]
  [[3, 4, 2], [8, 3, 4], [3, 2, 8]]
  ```
- El índice 2 se corresponde con el eje 1, la columna (coordenada <kbd>Y</kbd>):

  ```
  >>> img[3, 2]
  [3, 2, 8]
  ```
- El índice 0 se corresponde con el eje 2, el valor para el componente rojo del pixel:

  ```
  >>> img[3, 2, 1]
  0
  ```

`numpy.all` evalúa si todos los elementos de los arrays de un eje dado son verdaderos. Básicamente **lleva a cabo una reducción, de forma que ese eje termina solo con valores `True` o `False`, reduciendo los ejes superiores al mismo recursivamente a un boleano**. Imaginemos que hacemos:

```
np.all(img == (2, 5, 4), axis=2)
```

lo primero que se hace es evaluar `img == (2, 5, 4)`, esto se hace de forma vectorizada quedando un array de la forma:

```
[[[ True,  True,  True], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]],
 [[False,  True, False], [False, False, False], [False,  True, False]],
 [[ True, False, False], [ True,  True,  True], [False, False, False]],
 [[False, False, False], [False, False,  True], [False, False, False]]]
```

luego entra en acción `numpy.all`, como le hemos indicado que haga la comprobación sobre el eje 2, recorre cada array de dicho eje y mira si todos los elementos son `True`, por ejemplo:

> [False,  True, False] -> False
>   [ True,  True,  True] -> True

quedando al final:

```
 [[ True False False]
  [False False False]
  [False  True False]
  [False False False]]
```

con lo que sabemos que los pixeles `[0, 0]` y `[2, 1]` tienen el color `(2, 5, 4)`.

Posteriormente usas `numpy.any` que hace lo mismo que `all` pero en vez de comprobar que todos los items sean verdaderos, comprueba si al menos uno lo es:

> [False,  True, False] -> True
>   [ True,  True,  True] -> True
>   [False, False, False] -> False

si te fijas no se especifica ningún eje, en este caso `np.all`/`np.any` reducen todo el array (con todos los ejes) a un valor boleano. Por lo que la secuencia es:

> ```
> ]                          ]
>  [ True False False]  --->  True,   |
>  [False False False]  --->  False,  | ---> True 
>  [False  True False]  --->  True,   |
>  [False False False]  --->  False   |    
>  ]                          ]
> ```

---

dónde cada `--->` representa la pregunta:

> ¿Hay al menos un elemento que es verdadero?

---

> **Nota:** en Python en un condicional que comprueba algo se evalúa como `True` o `False` no iguales a `True` o `False`, usa simplemente `if` o `if not`:
>
> ```
> if a == False -> No
> if not a:     -> Si
>
> if a == True: -> No
> if a:         -> Si
> ```

Comment: Por lo tanto, el contenido de axis = 0 es la coordenada 'X', axis =1 la coordenada 'Y' y axis = 2 el 'color'?

Comment: Efectivamente, he editado la respuesta pormenorizando un poco más lo que hace el código que das como ejemplo.